# How to get current logged-in user details in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to get the values of current logged-in user, like user email, phone, firstName, lastName, and use in a form field. Maybe I am not doing it right. I have tried using hooks but did not work.

Here is my reducer, maybe I did not do it right.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  firstName: {},
  lastName: {},
  phone: {},
  email: {},
  password:{},
}

const ricozoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'ricozo',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.firstName = action.payload
      state.lastName = action.payload
      state.phone = action.payload
      state.email = action.payload
      state.password = action.payload
    },
    currentUser: (state, action) => {
      state.firstName = action.payload
      state.lastName = action.payload
      state.phone = action.payload
      state.email = action.payload
      state.password = action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const { addUser, currentUser} = ricozoSlice.actions

export default ricozoSlice.reducer
```

I tried to display the current user on a page but did not work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, input, style, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ricozo, currentUser, email, phone } from './redux/ricozoSlice'

function UserEmail(props) {
  const email = useSelector((state) => state.ricozo.email)
  //const phone = useSelector((state) => state.ricozo.phone)
  const phone = useSelector((state) => state.ricozo[props.phone])
  const firstName = useSelector((state) => state.ricozo.firstName)

  return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
      <Text>hello </Text>
      <Text>{phone}</Text>
      <Text>{email}</Text>
      <Text>{firstName}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
  background: {
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
})

export default UserEmail;
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue or problem with the code? Assuming you've correctly configured a redux store and provided it to the app, and the selector function is correct, then I don't see any overt issue with the code snippets you've shared. Do you populate the state somewhere, i.e. dispatch either of the `addUser` or `currentUser` actions with an appropriate payload?

Comment: Thank you for your time to go through this. i really appreciate. i intend sending a post request to a server and i want one of the field values(userPhone, userEmail) be picked from the currentUser logged in. please i need help on how to achieve this. also, can you advice me on the best way to create a user profile in react native? Thank you so much

Comment: The user data the code is selecting from state needs to exist, either by initializing the state values, or dispatching an action to update/populate the state. From there the code you've shared should be able to select the data and do what it needs with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I had to re-write my reducer to accept an empty state variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).